# How to resize image background depends of screen size?

Tags: html, css

I want to have resizable border with following building silhouette. Can just make that like background image of this block.
[image]

But when this comes to different screen size with current approach I have to have different bg image for each screen size.
One of idea is get this building image and with position absolute and media query set that on place that I want, but I believe that is better way to achieve that.
[image]

Comment: Switch between different images using media queries

Comment: Alternatively, you might want to use an absolute positioned image instead of setting it as background. I suspect background image isn't that flexible. As for sizing, you could set the border thickness and the image size in viewport width units (vw), making them proportional to the screen width.

Answer (score 0):

CSS media query will help you out check out small code given below.

Hope it may help !!

```
.imagePart{
     background-image : url('img1.png');
}

//max width based on your needs 

@media screen and (max-width : 680px){
  .imagePart{
     background-image : url('img2.png');
  }
}
```